# Output log using FtpWebRequest

Tags: c#, logging, ftp, ftpwebrequest

I wonder if it's possible to have output log for my FTP client using `FtpWebRequest`.

Something like this:

```
[R] USER xxx
[R] 331 Please specify the password.
[R] PASS (hidden)
[R] 230 Login successful.
[R] SYST
[R] 215 UNIX Type: L8
[R] FEAT
[R] 211-Features:
[R]  EPRT
[R]  EPSV
[R]  MDTM
[R]  PASV
[R]  REST STREAM
[R]  SIZE
[R]  TVFS
[R] 211 End
[R] PWD
[R] 257 "/"
[R] CWD /
[R] 250 Directory successfully changed.
[R] PWD
[R] 257 "/"
[R] TYPE A
[R] 200 Switching to ASCII mode.
[R] PASV
[R] 227 Entering Passive Mode (10,232,201,81,141,175)
[R] Opening data connection IP: 10.232.201.81 PORT: 36271
[R] LIST -al
[R] 150 Here comes the directory listing.
[R] 226 Directory send OK.
```

This output for example is when connecting...

My current code only does the following:

```
// Get the object used to communicate with the server.
FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(string.Format("ftp://{0}", addrEndPoint));
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectoryDetails;
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(_currentConnection.Username, _currentConnection.Password);

FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader(responseStream, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);

if (readStream != null)
{
    Console.WriteLine(readStream.ReadToEnd());
}
```

Answer (score 14):

You can do this using [Network Tracing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hyb3xww8.aspx). To [set it up](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty48b824.aspx), create (or modify, if you already have one) `App.config` file, so that it looks like this (if you already have the file, you will need to add the settings to it):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
      <source name="System.Net" tracemode="protocolonly" maxdatasize="1024">
        <listeners>
          <add name="System.Net"/>
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
    <switches>
      <add name="System.Net" value="Information"/>
    </switches>
    <sharedListeners>
      <add name="System.Net"
        type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener"
        initializeData="network.log"
      />
    </sharedListeners>
    <trace autoflush="true"/>
  </system.diagnostics>
</configuration>
```

If you do this, your application will create a `network.log` file, that might look something like this:

```
System.Net Information: 1 : [8892] FtpWebRequest#2383799::.ctor(ftp://test/)
System.Net Information: 0 : [8892] FtpWebRequest#2383799::GetResponse(Method=LIST.)
System.Net Information: 0 : [8892] Current OS installation type is 'Client'.
System.Net Information: 0 : [8892] RAS supported: True
System.Net Information: 0 : [8892] FtpControlStream#33675143 - Created connection from 192.168.1.1:51833 to 192.168.1.2:21.
System.Net Information: 0 : [8892] Associating FtpWebRequest#2383799 with FtpControlStream#33675143
System.Net Information: 0 : [8892] FtpControlStream#33675143 - Received response [220 This is the test FTP server. Authentication required.]
System.Net Information: 0 : [8892] FtpControlStream#33675143 - Sending command [USER svick]
System.Net Information: 0 : [8892] FtpControlStream#33675143 - Received response [331 Password required for svick]
System.Net Information: 0 : [8892] FtpControlStream#33675143 - Sending command [PASS ********]
System.Net Information: 0 : [8892] FtpControlStream#33675143 - Received response [230 Logged on]
System.Net Information: 0 : [8892] FtpControlStream#33675143 - Sending command [OPTS utf8 on]
System.Net Information: 0 : [8892] FtpControlStream#33675143 - Received response [200 UTF8 mode enabled]
System.Net Information: 0 : [8892] FtpControlStream#33675143 - Sending command [PWD]
System.Net Information: 0 : [8892] FtpControlStream#33675143 - Received response [257 "/" is current directory.]
System.Net Information: 0 : [8892] FtpControlStream#33675143 - Sending command [TYPE I]
System.Net Information: 0 : [8892] FtpControlStream#33675143 - Received response [200 Type set to I]
System.Net Information: 0 : [8892] FtpControlStream#33675143 - Sending command [PASV]
System.Net Information: 0 : [8892] FtpControlStream#33675143 - Received response [227 Entering Passive Mode (174,37,88,92,117,98)]
System.Net Information: 0 : [8892] FtpControlStream#33675143 - Sending command [LIST]
System.Net Information: 0 : [8892] FtpControlStream#33675143 - Received response [150 Connection accepted]
System.Net Information: 0 : [8892] FtpControlStream#33675143 - Received response [226 Transfer OK]
System.Net Information: 0 : [8892] FtpWebRequest#2383799::(Releasing FTP connection#33675143.)
```

It's quite verbose, but it does contain the information you need. If you want to modify how is the log file written, you can implement your own [`TraceListener`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.tracelistener.aspx) and use that in the config file instead of `TextWriterTraceListener`.

Comment: hi, the solution looks good and answer my expectations, but is it possible to get this info instead of writing to file ?

Comment: Yeah, I think you would create a class that inherits from `TraceListener` to do that, and use it in the config file.

Answer (score 0):

check these following links for reference. if you have IIS 7 then it is possible to implement your own functionality.

[implementing IFtpLogProvider interface's Log method](http://forums.iis.net/t/1154599.aspx)

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.Web.FtpServer;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Diagnostics.Eventing;

namespace FtpLogging
{
    public class FtpLogDemo : BaseProvider,
        IFtpLogProvider
    {
        void IFtpLogProvider.Log(FtpLogEntry loggingParameters)
        {
         .......
```

Ref:
[IIS FTP 7.5 Extensibility (IFtpLogProvider and logging FTP failures to the event log)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2032198/iis-ftp-7-5-extensibility-iftplogprovider-and-logging-ftp-failures-to-the-event)
[Problem writing to a file (C#)](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/netfxbcl/thread/b9b57092-5146-40e6-952b-3c757c2d61a0)