# Check if file exists on FTPS, Error 550

Tags: c#, .net, forms, ftp, file-exists

I trying to check if file exists on my FTP server but I get error "The remote server returned an error: (550) File unavailable" while my file already exists I sure it wasn't happen by my permission or wrong ip or wrong user, Because I can use FileZilla to edit my file with FTPUser20, And I copy `textBox4("textBox4.Text = (uploadto);")` and paste in my browser I can access.
Here is my code

```
public bool FtpDirectoryExists(string directoryPath, string ftpUser, string ftpPassword)
{
    bool IsExists = true;
    try
    {
        FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(directoryPath);
        request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(ftpUser, ftpPassword);
        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.PrintWorkingDirectory;
        FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
    }
    catch (WebException ex)
    {
        IsExists = false;
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
    return IsExists;
}

private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string uploadto;
    severip = textBox1.Text;
    username = textBox2.Text;
    password = textBox3.Text;
    uploadto = ("ftp://" + severip + ":1919/" + "IMG/"+ username + ".png");
    textBox4.Text = (uploadto);
    //check if exists
    bool result = FtpDirectoryExists(uploadto, "FTPUser20", "12345");
}
```

please help me. My file already exists.

Comment: does the folder IMG exist?

Comment: I've edited your question to remove the C# tag from the  title. Read why: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles

Comment: My file already exists. I'm sorry I forgot to tell

Comment: catch the exception to get more details:  String status = ((FtpWebResponse)e.Response).StatusDescription;

Comment: 550 the filename directory name or volume label syntax is incorrect. 
Win32 error: the filename directory name or volume label syntax is incorrect.
Error details: file system returned an error.
End

I use windows 8 Pro, IIS8.0

Comment: ok your file path is not correct check if you miss a slash somewhere

Comment: @MUG4N This is what show in textBox4 ftp://192.168.2.11:1919/IMG/test.png I coppy this address and paste in chorme browser I can access the file. What I wrong :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try your code with a double slash at the end:

```
uploadto = ("ftp://" + severip + ":1919//" + "IMG/"+ username + ".png")
```

you should also try this approach:

```
uploadto = ("ftp://ftp." + severip + ":1919//" + "IMG/"+ username + ".png")
```

try to change your request method like this:

```
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;
```

Comment: uploadto = ("ftp://" + severip + ":1919//" + "IMG/"+ username + ".png")
uploadto = ("ftp://" + severip + ":1919//" + "IMG//"+ username + ".png")
Give me the same error
uploadto = ("ftp://ftp." + severip + ":1919//" + "IMG/"+ username + ".png")
Give me new error "the remote name could not be resolved"

Comment: my last idea: check your security settings in your iis: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17471745/ftp-getresponse-error-550-file-unavailable?rq=1

Comment: Sloved request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile; working Thanks :D
sorry I can't vote up I don't have reputation enought