# FTP list content with incomplete file

Tags: c#, .net, ftp

I am trying to build a list of all files on a ftp server.

```
// Get the object used to communicate with the server.
            FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(remote);
            request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(userName, passWord);
            request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory;
            FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
            List<string> files = new List<string>();

            // Build List of all files
            string line = streamReader.ReadLine();
            while (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line))
            {
                files.Add(line);
                line = streamReader.ReadLine();
            }
            streamReader.Close();
```

Now, the problem is, whe i use this list with the broken/incomplete file to download all the files with a Webclient, the code breaks when trying to download the incomplete file...

> The remote server returned an error: (550) File unavailable (e.g.,
>   file not found, no access)

How can i skip these files when building the list?

Comment: Not sure on whether you can "skip" bad files, however you can try the code here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17471745/ftp-getresponse-error-550-file-unavailable to get a more exact error message.  From there you can trouble shoot with the FTP sites administrator to clear up the issue.

Comment: @Bearcat9425 Thank you. The files ar created in the ftp folder automaticly, but i want to skip the files that are not fully copied/created

Comment: I don't think there is a way to do this, at least wise I am not aware of.  I hope someone can say I am wrong and provide a solution but I don't think there is an out of the box one for this.  I would work with your FTP administrator to find out why an automated process is generating incomplete/bad files.  I would start there and work my way back.

Comment: What happens if you try checking the filesize (WebRequestMethods.Ftp.GetFileSize) as you create the list - if it returns 0 or throws an exception - you could use that to limit the list of files.

Comment: See also [How to detect that a file is being uploaded over FTP](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29238153/850848).

Comment: Doing some modifications and testing with GetFileSize... I'll get back on this...

Answer (score 0):

I the catch of the exeption i just added a "ignore" when the exeptions was "The remote server returned an error: (550) File unavailable (e.g., file not found, no access)"
This way i dont get the error and the file gets downloaded just fine when its complete on the ftp server.