# The remote server returned an error: (550) on upload file to FTP using FtpWebRequest

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, ftp, ftpwebrequest

I need to upload file via ftp to host. The `/home2/travele2` path created on the root of host
[image]

I can upload file via FileZilla program to the host, but when I try to upload file via website, it gets me this error:

> The remote server returned an error: (550) File unavailable (e.g., file not found, no access).

What is the problem?

```
// Get the object used to communicate with the server.  
FtpWebRequest ftpWebRequest = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://00.00.00.00/home2/travele2");
ftpWebRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
// This example assumes the FTP site uses anonymous logon.  
ftpWebRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("aaaaaaa", "0000000");

// Copy the contents of the file to the request stream.  
StreamReader sourceStream = new StreamReader(Server.MapPath("/Content/Site.pdf"));
byte[] fileContents = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sourceStream.ReadToEnd());
sourceStream.Close();
ftpWebRequest.ContentLength = fileContents.Length;

Stream requestStream = ftpWebRequest.GetRequestStream();
requestStream.Write(fileContents, 0, fileContents.Length);
requestStream.Close();

FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)ftpWebRequest.GetResponse();

Console.WriteLine("Upload File Complete, status {0}", response.StatusDescription);

response.Close();
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The URL has to include a target file name:

```
string url = "ftp://ftp.example.com/home2/travele2/Site.pdf";
FtpWebRequest ftpWebRequest = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
```

*How else would the `FtpWebRequest` know, what name to use?*

---

And once you have that solved, you will find out that the upload corrupts the file, as you treat the file as UTF-8-encoded text. What is nonsense, as a PDF is a binary file.

For a correct code, see:
[Upload and download a file to/from FTP server in C#/.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44606028/850848)

Answer (score -2):

The way you load your sourceStream looks kind of fishy.. I would recommend to download a nuget library ftp client, it will make your life a lot easier. FluentFTP is a good choice with good documentation and examples.

Check it out:
https://github.com/robinrodricks/FluentFTP

Comment: When recommending a software, you should explicitly state if you are affiliated to the project or not.

Comment: First of all it's an open source library... And no I'm not related in any way to this project.