# Uploading File To FTP Location Throws Error

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, vb.net-2010

Using the below code to upload file to my FTP location but I am getting the below error.

I checked the FTP Location / username and password with FileZilla and everything is working fine and also I can able to create file manually in Filezilla.  So there is no rights issue I believe.

> The remote server returned an error: (550) File unavailable (e.g.,
>   file not found, no access)

```
Sub FTPFileUpload()
    Dim sFTPSaveLoc As String, sLocalSysFilePath As String

    sLocalSysFilePath = "D:/9100.txt"
    sFTPSaveLoc = "ftp://MyFTPIPAddressHere/ftp/DB/9100.txt"

    My.Computer.Network.UploadFile(sLocalSysFilePath, sFTPSaveLoc, "FTPUserIDHere", "FTPPasswordHere")

End Sub
```

Any suggestion will be highly helpful.

Comment: Does the directory `/ftp/DB` exist? Ensure you have write permissions to it as well.

Comment: Yes exists and I can able to create file manually in /ftp/DB folder using filezilla but I can't get it work with the above code. Whether the above code is working for you?

Comment: Sorry, but I am currently in no position to test it. I found this, though. It's worth a shot: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27487095

Comment: Thank you.... You fixed it.... The /ftp/ is a shared folder which I should not use when using the FTP path.  I removed it and its working fine now.  Please post your suggestion as Answer I will mark it as answer.

Comment: When I see it in filezilla it doesn't show /ftp/ in the directory listing.  So your reply given me clue that I am unnecessarily using the /ftp/ in the FTP location connection string.  Thanks once again.

Comment: Glad I could help, but I barely suggested anything :). Since it was caused by a typo I'm just going to vote to close it as such instead.