# FTPWebRequest: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive

Tags: c#, ftp

I've got a problem when uploading files to my FTP server. This connection usually works fine over a local connection - however, im trying to connect to the Public IP address of a system (ftp://xx.xxx.xxx.xx). I can connect to it just fine over filezilla to upload and download files - however, for some reason this just does not seem to work.

This is the code im using to create the WebRequest:

```
FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://xx.xxx.xx.xxx" + uploadPath);
request.UseBinary = true; 
request.KeepAlive = false;
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
```

That runs fine in debug mode, all the filepaths are allowed, etc.. However, the code is throwing an error in this section here:

```
byte[] b = File.ReadAllBytes(tarPath);
request.ContentLength = b.Length;
using (Stream s = request.GetRequestStream())
{
    s.Write(b, 0, b.Length);
}
FtpWebResponse ftpResp = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
if (ftpResp != null)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(ftpResp.StatusDescription);
}
```

Any Ideas? I've searched through the various online posts about this error and most of them are in regards to HTTPWebRequest, not FTPWebRequest. So if this code works over a local connection, then why is it acting like this over a global connection?

Thanks in advance

EDIT
As requested, i've enabled network logging and here is the output - Bare in mind i've changed our public Server IP to 00x000x00x000 for security reasons and that is not an error ! :)

```
System.Net Information: 0 : [7120] FtpWebRequest#35287174::.ctor(ftp://00.000.00.000/users/be83dec5d120c42a6b94/119ab9d171cce2528d9a.tar)
System.Net Information: 0 : [7120] FtpWebRequest#35287174::GetRequestStream(Method=STOR.)
System.Net Information: 0 : [7120] Current OS installation type is 'Client'.
System.Net Information: 0 : [7120] RAS supported: True
System.Net Error: 0 : [7120] Can't retrieve proxy settings for Uri 'ftp://00.000.00.000/users/be83dec5d120c42a6b94/119ab9d171cce2528d9a.tar'. Error code: 12180.
System.Net Information: 0 : [7120] FtpControlStream#10261382 - Created connection from 192.168.0.48:15275 to 00.000.00.000:21.
System.Net Information: 0 : [7120] Associating FtpWebRequest#35287174 with FtpControlStream#10261382
System.Net Information: 0 : [7120] FtpControlStream#10261382 - Received response [220 (vsFTPd 3.0.2)]
System.Net Information: 0 : [7120] FtpControlStream#10261382 - Sending command [USER dev]
System.Net Information: 0 : [7120] FtpControlStream#10261382 - Received response [331 Please specify the password.]
System.Net Information: 0 : [7120] FtpControlStream#10261382 - Sending command [PASS ********]
System.Net Information: 0 : [7120] FtpControlStream#10261382 - Received response [230 Login successful.]
System.Net Information: 0 : [7120] FtpControlStream#10261382 - Sending command [OPTS utf8 on]
System.Net Information: 0 : [7120] FtpControlStream#10261382 - Received response [200 Always in UTF8 mode.]
System.Net Information: 0 : [7120] FtpControlStream#10261382 - Sending command [PWD]
System.Net Information: 0 : [7120] FtpControlStream#10261382 - Received response [257 "/home/dev"]
System.Net Information: 0 : [7120] FtpControlStream#10261382 - Sending command [TYPE I]
System.Net Information: 0 : [7120] FtpControlStream#10261382 - Received response [200 Switching to Binary mode.]
System.Net Information: 0 : [7120] FtpControlStream#10261382 - Sending command [PASV]
System.Net Information: 0 : [7120] FtpControlStream#10261382 - Received response [227 Entering Passive Mode (58,104,53,147,24,79).]
System.Net Information: 0 : [7120] FtpControlStream#10261382 - Sending command [STOR users/be83dec5d120c42a6b94/119ab9d171cce2528d9a.tar]
System.Net Information: 0 : [7120] FtpControlStream#10261382 - Received response [150 Ok to send data.]
System.Net Information: 0 : [5756] ServicePoint#22597652 - Closed as idle.
System.Net Information: 0 : [7120] FtpWebRequest#35287174::(Releasing FTP connection#10261382.)
System.Net Error: 0 : [7120] Exception in AppDomain#4032828::UnhandledExceptionHandler - The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive..
   at System.Net.FtpWebRequest.SyncRequestCallback(Object obj)
   at System.Net.FtpWebRequest.RequestCallback(Object obj)
   at System.Net.CommandStream.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
   at System.IO.Stream.Close()
   at System.IO.Stream.Dispose()
   at System.Net.ConnectionPool.Destroy(PooledStream pooledStream)
   at System.Net.ConnectionPool.PutConnection(PooledStream pooledStream, Object owningObject, Int32 creationTimeout, Boolean canReuse)
   at System.Net.FtpWebRequest.FinishRequestStage(RequestStage stage)
   at System.Net.FtpWebRequest.SyncRequestCallback(Object obj)
   at System.Net.FtpWebRequest.RequestCallback(Object obj)
   at System.Net.CommandStream.Abort(Exception e)
   at System.Net.CommandStream.CheckContinuePipeline()
   at System.Net.FtpWebRequest.DataStreamClosed(CloseExState closeState)
   at System.Net.FtpDataStream.System.Net.ICloseEx.CloseEx(CloseExState closeState)
   at System.Net.FtpDataStream.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
   at System.IO.Stream.Close()
   at System.IO.Stream.Dispose()
   at tcpClient.ftpClass.upload(String tarPath, String uploadPath) in c:\Users\Adam\Desktop\Project\Workspace\Network\SafeSpotService\SafeSpotClient\SafeSpotClient\ftpClass.cs:line 84
   at SafeSpotClient.Service1.checkInCycle(String macAddr) in c:\Users\Adam\Desktop\Project\Workspace\Network\SafeSpotService\SafeSpotClient\SafeSpotClient\Service1.cs:line 121
   at SafeSpotClient.Service1.Callback(Object state) in c:\Users\Adam\Desktop\Project\Workspace\Network\SafeSpotService\SafeSpotClient\SafeSpotClient\Service1.cs:line 168
   at System.Threading.TimerQueueTimer.CallCallbackInContext(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.TimerQueueTimer.CallCallback()
   at System.Threading.TimerQueueTimer.Fire()
   at System.Threading.TimerQueue.FireNextTimers()
   at System.Threading.TimerQueue.AppDomainTimerCallback()
```

Comment: what's your FtpWebRequest.Timeout value ?

Comment: Havent set it so it should be default val.... Usually i receive a response back within 20 seconds of uploading so there's no need to change the value as it defaults to 100 seconds?

Comment: [Enable logging](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9664650/850848) and show us the log. Exception callstack may help too.

Comment: Check the OP for edit containing network log dumps !!

Comment: Do you have an access to FTP server log? Did it even receive the data connection attempt?

Comment: Is the IP address in `PASV` response correct? `58,104,53,147`?

Comment: Yes it is. I do have access to the server logs. But im assuming everythings fine server side because the file gets uploaded to the server correctly... Could it be because im trying to upload outside of the apache dir?

Comment: Anyone have any ideas? Really stuck on this :/

Comment: did u ever get answer?