# Read FTP file from Azure VM or Azure WebJob

Tags: azure, ftp, readfile, ftpwebrequest, ftpwebresponse

I have created a console application which reads a **CSV** file from **FTP** server and dump the records after validation to database.

When I tried the code from my local machine, its working perfectly. No errors, no bugs. But when I put it on a Azure Virtual Machine to schedule it.
OR When I create a Azure WebJob to create a schedule Job, I am getting following error while accessing the file.

> The remote server returned an error: (500) Syntax error, command
>   unrecognized. at System.Net.FtpWebRequest.SyncRequestCallback(Object
>   obj) at System.Net.FtpWebRequest.RequestCallback(Object obj) at
>   System.Net.CommandStream.Dispose(Boolean disposing) at
>   System.IO.Stream.Close() at System.IO.Stream.Dispose() at
>   System.Net.ConnectionPool.Destroy(PooledStream pooledStream) at
>   System.Net.ConnectionPool.PutConnection(PooledStream pooledStream,
>   Object owningObject, Int32 creationTimeout, Boolean canReuse) at
>   System.Net.FtpWebRequest.FinishRequestStage(RequestStage stage) at
>   System.Net.FtpWebRequest.GetResponse() at
>   Bethesda_DataUpload.Program.Main(String[] args) in
>   D:\Projects\Program.cs:line 35

I am using following code to connect to FTP server

```
    string dataFile = "ftp://testftp-L.cloudapp.net/Inbound/sampleFile.csv";
    FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(new Uri(dataFile));
    request.UsePassive = false;
    request.UseBinary = true;
    request.KeepAlive = true;
    request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(ftpUsrName, ftpPassword);
    request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;
    request.Proxy = WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy;
    request.ImpersonationLevel = System.Security.Principal.TokenImpersonationLevel.Impersonation;

    List<string> entries = new List<string>();


    using (FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
    {
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            entries = reader.ReadToEnd().Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList();
        }
    }
```

I have tried all the combinations of **KeepAlive** and **UsePassive** like

**Combination 1**

```
request.UsePassive = false;
request.KeepAlive = false;
```

**Combination 2**

```
request.UsePassive = false;
request.KeepAlive = true;
```

**Combination 3**

```
request.UsePassive = true;
request.KeepAlive = false;
```

**Combination 4**

```
request.UsePassive = true;
request.KeepAlive = true;
```

What code I should use?

Comment: No point trying `request.UsePassive = false;` on Azure Web site, it cannot work. Show us what you get with the `request.UsePassive = true;` (= the default).

Comment: + Ideally [enable logging](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9664650/850848) and show us the log (for `UsePassive = true`).

Comment: The error I have mentioned is the same when I am using UsePassive = false; When I use UserPassive = true; "It says The remote server returned an error: 227 Entering Passive Mode (100,109,40,49,47,42)."

Comment: Forgot to mention, the FTP Server is Linux Azure VM and we were trying to access the files from Windows Azure VM using above mentioned code. 
I couldn't manage to do network trace yet.