# Uploading file with FtpWebRequest from an azure hosted application to an external ftp site

Tags: vb.net, azure, file-upload, ftp, ftpwebrequest

> **UPDATE: I found out that it is not an issue with azure rather the
>   other party who are actually doing white-listing on incoming
>   connection.**

I implemented a service, which open and ftp connection to upload a file to a remote FTP server. **The code works perfectly (!) running on my desktop, however if I publish it to the azure hosting cloud and execute with exactly the same parameters I get WebException with the message 'The remote server returned an error: (530) Not logged in.'** I haven't found any relevant setting in the azure console. I also tried different setting like on/off keep-alive and passive, but the result are the same. Do you guys have an idea what could be the problem?

The code for reference:

```
            Dim request As FtpWebRequest

            request = TryCast(WebRequest.Create($"ftp://{_host}/inventory/{_uploadFilename}"), FtpWebRequest)
            request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile
            request.Credentials = New NetworkCredential(_username, _password)
            request.UsePassive = True
            request.UseBinary = True
            request.KeepAlive = False

            Using fs As FileStream = File.OpenRead(_fileName)
                Dim buffer As Byte() = New Byte(fs.Length - 1) {}
                fs.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)
                fs.Close()
                Dim requestStream As Stream = request.GetRequestStream()
                requestStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)
                requestStream.Flush()
                requestStream.Close()


                Dim response As FtpWebResponse = DirectCast(request.GetResponse(), FtpWebResponse)
                Return Ok($"Remote server response: {response.StatusDescription}")

            End Using
```

Comment: [Enable logging](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9664650/850848) and show us a log both from your desktop and the Azure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that it is not an issue with azure rather the other party who are actually doing white-listing on incoming connection.

Answer (score 1):

Where is `NetworkCredential` getting credentials from?

Windows Authentication (Kerberos/NTLM) won't work in Azure. You need to use FTP login (as in `USER` and `PASS` FTP commands).

Always use **PASSIVE** mode when attempting FTP transfer from Azure.

```vb
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Net

Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim request As FtpWebRequest
        Dim _host = "remote.ftpserver.com"
        Dim _uploadFilename = "file.txt"
        Dim _filename = "file.txt"
        Dim _username = "Username"
        Dim _password = "PaSsw0rD"

        request = TryCast(WebRequest.Create($"ftp://{_host}/path/{_uploadFilename}"),
            FtpWebRequest)
        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile
        request.Credentials = New NetworkCredential(_username, _password)
        request.UsePassive = True
        request.UseBinary = True
        request.KeepAlive = False

        Using fs As FileStream = File.OpenRead(_filename)
            Dim buffer As Byte() = New Byte(fs.Length - 1) {}
            fs.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)
            fs.Close()
            Dim requestStream As Stream = request.GetRequestStream()
            requestStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)
            requestStream.Flush()
            requestStream.Close()
            Dim response As FtpWebResponse = DirectCast(request.GetResponse(),
                FtpWebResponse)
            Console.WriteLine($"Remote server response: {response.StatusCode}, 
                {response.StatusDescription}")
        End Using
    End Sub

End Module
```

Apologies if the formatting is all over the place. This is my first attempt at writing VB.

Running this in [Kudu's DebugConsole](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Kudu-console) for clarity - same sandbox as the Web App:

[image: Run-in-Kudu]

On the remote FTP server:

```
ftp> ls file.txt
200 PORT command successful.
125 Data connection already open; Transfer starting.
file.txt
226 Transfer complete.
ftp: 13 bytes received in 0.02Seconds 0.81Kbytes/sec.

ftp> bin
200 Type set to I.

ftp> get file.txt
200 PORT command successful.
125 Data connection already open; Transfer starting.
226 Transfer complete.
ftp: 24 bytes received in 0.18Seconds 0.14Kbytes/sec.

ftp> !type file.txt
Upped with FtpWebRequest
```

Comment: Thank you for take a look at my problem, however I think it is not about being a kerberos authentication. It is just a simple basic one. I run the code on a local ftp server, and here is the relevant commands executed: 

2016-09-28 19:16:48 ::1 - ::1 21 USER anonymous 331 0 0 72cfd8e0-20c5-48ad-af21-df2443de8605 -

2016-09-28 19:16:48 ::1 - ::1 21 PASS devtest@helloka.com 230 0 0 72cfd8e0-20c5-48ad-af21-df2443de8605 /

However I'm kinda interested how did you do testing. Did you somehow upload a vb console application to azure?

Comment: Yes. Drag and drop into the Kudu console. Link in my answer.