# The remote server returned an error: (530) (Not logged in)

Tags: vb.net, ftp

I have changed the credentials etc at the bottom of course for security reasons, but could anyone offer any suggestions as to why this isn't working?

I have used these credentials on FileZilla with no problems.

Code:

```
Imports System.Net
Imports System.IO

Public Class Form1

Private Sub FtpUploadFile(ByVal filetoupload As String, ByVal ftpuri As String, ByVal ftpusername As String, ByVal ftppassword As String)
    ' Create a web request that will be used to talk with the server and set the request method to upload a file by ftp.
    Dim ftpRequest As FtpWebRequest = CType(WebRequest.Create(ftpuri), FtpWebRequest)

    Try
        ftpRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile

        ' Confirm the Network credentials based on the user name and password passed in.
        ftpRequest.Credentials = New NetworkCredential(ftpusername, ftppassword)

        ' Read into a Byte array the contents of the file to be uploaded 
        Dim bytes() As Byte = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filetoupload)

        ' Transfer the byte array contents into the request stream, write and then close when done.
        ftpRequest.ContentLength = bytes.Length
        Using UploadStream As Stream = ftpRequest.GetRequestStream()
            UploadStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)
            UploadStream.Close()
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        Exit Sub
    End Try

    MessageBox.Show("Process Complete")
End Sub

Private Sub Upload_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Upload.Click
    FtpUploadFile("D:\Directory\Filename.csv", "ftp://www.****.com/test.csv", "****@*****.com", "*********")
End Sub
End Class
```

as requested I have tried to use WebClient see below code
        Try

```
    Dim up As New WebClient
        up.Credentials = New NetworkCredential("username", "password")
    up.UploadFile("ftp://www.domain.com/test.csv", "D:\test\test.csv")
        MsgBox("Done")
        up.Dispose()

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

the results are the same;
The remote server returned an error: (530) (Not logged in)

Comment: Looks right at a glance...have you tried using [WebClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient(v=vs.110).aspx) instead?

Comment: no... i'll try now.. good idea!

Comment: @MrGadget i'll not lie, looked into WebClient and haven't got a clue where to start! any suggestions?

Comment: [WebClient.UploadFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36s52zhs(v=vs.110).aspx) has an example. It takes a NetworkCredential the same way FtpWebRequest does. Should be 4 lines of code counting the Dispose.

Comment: Thanks @MrGadget. I know it should probably mean something to me, but it doesn't. I'll have to keep studying to try and get more help. Thanks for your time

Comment: Hi @MrGadget I have tried the WebClient.uploadFile and the same error is returned.

Comment: Show us [log file](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9664650/850848).

Comment: Though it's quite likely that your credentials are simply wrong. Can you login using the same credentials using a standalone FTP client (e.g. WinSCP)? Show us its log! Do you have any special characters in the credentials?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl my credentials are correct. I enabled SSL and it works fine now. Thanks for the response.

Answer (score -1):

Try This:

```
Try

        Dim ftp_webrequest As FtpWebRequest = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create("ftp://domainname/filename"), FtpWebRequest)


        With ftp_webrequest
            .EnableSsl = False
            .UsePassive = False
            .Credentials = New NetworkCredential("username", "password")
            .Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile
        End With
        Dim file() As Byte = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("filepath")

        Dim strz As System.IO.Stream = ftp_webrequest.GetRequestStream()
        strz.Write(file, 0, file.Length)
        strz.Close()
        strz.Dispose()

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
```

Comment: Why should this help? There's hardly any difference to OP code. Except that you suggest use of active mode. What cannot help with this particular error; and will likely introduce even more problems.

Comment: Hi, I solved this, I had to Enable SSL for it to work.
Thanks