# uploading file to FTP with TSL/SSL explicit encryption giving error

Tags: c#-4.0, ftp, file-transfer

I have to upload files to a ftp site. i am able transfer file to that ftp folder using **WINSCP**

Now I am trying the same using c# with below code

```
FtpWebRequest ftpClient = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(
"ftp://ftps-xxxxx.xxx.xx.com:xxx/folder/text.txt");
         ftpClient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "password");
          ftpClient.Method = System.Net.WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
          ftpClient.UseBinary = true;
          ftpClient.KeepAlive = true;
          System.IO.FileInfo fi = new System.IO.FileInfo(@"C:\d\text.txt");
          ftpClient.ContentLength = fi.Length;
          byte[] buffer = new byte[4097];
          int bytes = 0;
          int total_bytes = (int)fi.Length;
          System.IO.FileStream fs = fi.OpenRead();
          ftpClient.KeepAlive = false;
          ftpClient.Timeout = -1;
          System.IO.Stream rs = ftpClient.GetRequestStream();
          while (total_bytes > 0)
          {
             bytes = fs.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
             rs.Write(buffer, 0, bytes);
             total_bytes = total_bytes - bytes;
           }
          fs.Close();
          rs.Close();
          FtpWebResponse uploadResponse = (FtpWebResponse)ftpClient.GetResponse();
          string value = uploadResponse.StatusDescription;
          uploadResponse.Close();
```

when it reach `System.IO.Stream rs = ftpClient.GetRequestStream();`
below error is occuring

> The remote server returned an error: (500) Syntax error, command
>   unrecognized.

Comment: Using a traditional client with given URL and credentials works?
Why `KeepAlive = true` then `false` a little later?

Comment: You can easily simplify you transfer request as given in MSDN : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229715(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @ArnaudF. just tried with `false` also forget to remove the `true` from beginning..Also yes using WINSCP client for the same url and credentials works

Comment: [Enable logging](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9664650/850848) and show us the log + Show us WinSCP log.

Comment: Also you claim you have problems with TLS/SSL, yet I do not see anything in your code that you enable it.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl thanks one of the issue was not enabling it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need to reinvent the wheel, simply transfer like this:

```
        using (System.Net.WebClient c = new System.Net.WebClient())
        {
            c.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "password");
            c.UploadFile("ftp://...", @"C:\d\test.txt");
        }
```

Comment: `The remote server returned an error: (500) Syntax error, command unrecognized.`

Comment: Do you have an inner Exception? Is it `ftp` or `sftp`?

Comment: inner exception is null..It is ftp. through winscp im using the protocol ftp

Comment: its FTPS with explicit SSL

Comment: Add `EnableSSL = true` then

Comment: needed to attach the SSL certificate also along with c# code. I done the necessary coding for that along with SSL enabled and it got worked