# loading file to ftp site giving error :System : The remote server returned an error: 125 Data connection already open; transfer starting

Tags: c#, file-upload, ftp

I am trying to upload some txt files to ftp site as below.

```
FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("FTP PATH");
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
request.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(username, password);
request.EnableSsl = true;
X509Certificate cert = X509Certificate.CreateFromCertFile(certificate path);
X509CertificateCollection certCollection = new X509CertificateCollection();
certCollection.Add(cert);
request.ClientCertificates = certCollection;
StreamReader sourceStream = new StreamReader("localfile path to upload");
 byte[] fileContents = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sourceStream.ReadToEnd());
 sourceStream.Close();
 request.ContentLength = fileContents.Length;
 Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
 requestStream.Write(fileContents, 0, fileContents.Length);
 requestStream.Close();
FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
response.StatusDescription);
 writelog("response:.."+response.StatusDescription);
 response.Close();
```

and its uploading the files some time and sometime iam encoutering with an error.
please check below logs

**Successful Log**

```
4/12/2017 10:43:16 AM:Uploading file to ftp
4/12/2017 10:43:21 AM:response:..226 Closing data connection, Binary transfer complete.

4/12/2017 10:43:21 AM:end Uploading file to ftp
```

**Failure Log**

> > 4/12/2017 10:43:22 AM:Uploading file to ftp
> >     4/12/2017 10:43:23 AM :
> >     System : The remote server returned an error: 125 Data connection
> >     already open; transfer starting.

I am not able to identify the issue please help

Comment: Show us a log file - http://stackoverflow.com/q/9664650/850848 + Do you get similar problems with a standalone FTP client?

Comment: Are there any thing in common for files that fail or ones that succeed?

Comment: @BugFinder all files will contain only some text