# Error 550: the specified network name is no longer available when download file from ftp server with C#

Tags: c#, ftpwebrequest

I am writing an application C# to download a file from ftp server, using Ftpwebrequest. I tested with a ftp server and my application worked fine. But when it works in real system (ftp server runs windows server 2008), it throw an exception: **Error 550: the specified network name is no longer available**. Anyone know how to resolve this problem? Thank you.

Comment: Without any code, we can only guess - but my guess is somewhere in your code or settings you are referring to a network name that exists in your development environment but is inaccessible in the production environment.  I suggest you post your code and specify exactly where error is occurring.

Comment: Have you seen my code?

Comment: Ftp server uses ports: 66, 68, 88..., not default port. Do they cause error?

Comment: On the computer where you code isn't working, have you tried logging into the ftp server using the same credentials manually (e.g. via browser or other FTP client).  Also check anti-virus and this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44107643/c-sharp-ftp-response-550the-specified-network-name-is-no-longer-available

Comment: I tried connecting to ftp server with File zilla client and window explorer. They connect successfully.

Comment: Ftp server use kaspersky anti virus. But I think it does not cause error because file zilla client abd window explorer still connect successfully

Comment: It's the antivirus on the client PC you need to check in case it's wrongly identifying your program as a threat. Maybe briefly disable the AV & Firewall on the client PC while you test to rule it out.  Try it on other PCs. Double check it really does run compiled on your PC. Write trace lines in your code to print out status / erro info when running on client PC.  Basically keep testing till something exceptional or some pattern emerges that will give you a clue on where to look.

Comment: I tried to disabled antivrus, firewall and window defender but it still has error

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I forgot to post my code:

```
public static bool TestConnection(string IPAdd, string port, string username, string password)
    {
        try
        {
            var downloadRequest = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(@"ftp://" + IPAdd + ":" + port);
            downloadRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);
            downloadRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory;

            var ftpWebResponse = (FtpWebResponse)downloadRequest.GetResponse();
            ftpWebResponse.Close();
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```