# How to connect ftp server without Credentials?

Tags: c#, ftp

I problem with entering username/password to connect ftp server with credentials :

```
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(UserName, Password);
```

but when try to connect ftp server with username/password embed in address problem is solved :

```
ftp://usernamae:password@192.168.1.1:21
```

how can use this format in my code to connect ftp server :

```
FtpWebRequest request =
    (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://ftp.example.com/remote/path/file.zip");
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;

using (Stream ftpStream = request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream())
using (Stream fileStream = File.Create(@"C:\local\path\file.zip"))
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[10240];
    int read;
    while ((read = ftpStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
    {
        fileStream.Write(buffer, 0, read);
        Console.WriteLine("Downloaded {0} bytes", fileStream.Position);
    }
}
```

for example :

```
FtpWebRequest request =
    (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://username:password@ftp.example.com/remote/path/file.zip");
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;

using (Stream ftpStream = request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream())
using (Stream fileStream = File.Create(@"C:\local\path\file.zip"))
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[10240];
    int read;
    while ((read = ftpStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
    {
        fileStream.Write(buffer, 0, read);
        Console.WriteLine("Downloaded {0} bytes", fileStream.Position);
    }
}
```

Comment: Show us a [`FtpWebRequest` log file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9664650/850848) for both variants

Comment: @jonathana How could that help? OP needs to use specific credentials, not default credentials.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl, maybe you are right, the comment was deleted. but after reading the question again i think the problem is not the credentials: "but when try to connect ftp server with username/password embed in address problem is solved"

Comment: I don't think you can.  FTP has been around since the earlier 1970's.  Network credentials has been around for less than 10 years.  So entering username and password is a protocol that has been around for 45 years and you cannot not change it to a newer protocol.

Comment: @jdweng What do you mean by *"Network credentials has been around for less than 10 years"* - Quoting MSDN for [`NetworkCredential`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkcredential.aspx): *"Provides credentials for password-based authentication schemes such as basic, digest, NTLM, and Kerberos authentication."* - You can use `NetworkCredential` for simple FTP authentication. Basicaly both codes in OP are nearly equivalent and normally both work.

Comment: It depends on what the server is programmed to do.  Network credentials has been around since Net Framework 1.1.  So maybe 15 years instead of 10 , but a lot less than 45.

Comment: @jdweng OK, but FTP is not aware of .NET. The `NetworkCredential` is just an API to provide the credentials to FTP client implementation in .NET. The server does not care about `NetworkCredential`.

Comment: Make up your mind.  You said "Basicaly both codes in OP are nearly equivalent and normally both work".  Now you say network credentials does not work at server.

Comment: @Martin Prikryl  As I said, if you read it, I was referring to a scenario where a Ftp: (not Ftps:) server was rejecting a request using NetworkCredentials if SSL was active. But I have tested it, and I can't reproduce that behaviour. Maybe it's how the framework worked then (fw 3.5) and how works now (fw 4.7.1). By now, the OP code authenticates in both cases. So I deleted the answer. Maybe his problem is just a typo.

Comment: @jdweng There's no contradiction. `FtpWebRequest` just need a username and password. It does not matter, if is gets them from URL or `ICredentials` (implemented by `NetworkCredential`). The FTP server never tells a difference. Because `ICredentials` is not its API, it's an API of the `FtpWebRequest`. For FTP server, the API is `USER` and `PASS` commands.

Comment: @Tavakkoli Do you have any special characters in the password or username?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl no !

Comment: @Tavakkoli So it's only letters and digits? If that's correct, show us logs finally, as I have asked you already yesterday.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl the log is :drwxrwxrwx   1 0        0        4096 Nov 20  2016 usb1_1
drwxr-xr-x   3 0        0        0 Jan 01  1970 .
drwxrwxr-x  14 609      609      212 Jul 25  2016 ..

Comment: That's not `FtpWebRequest` log. [`FtpWebRequest` log is an XML file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9664650/850848) + Once you get the real log, append it to your question, do not post it in comments.