# Getting "This server requires encryption" when connecting to FTP server in C#

Tags: c#, .net, ssl, ftp, ftpwebrequest

I want to upload a XML file on FTP via Code with unity, but i can't connect to the FTP first.

So before uploading I just try to access FTP and list directory.

I use this code:

```
FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(host);
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectoryDetails;

request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(user, pass);

FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
Debug.Log(string.Format("Directory List Complete, status {0}", response.StatusDescription));

response.Close();
```

But I always have the same error :

> Error :
>   [Exception] Exception The authentication or decryption has failed.
>
> Error :
>   [Exception] Exception Server returned an error: 550-This server requires encryption.
>   550 You must issue the AUTH command to change to an encrypted session before you can attempt to login.

Looking for other post, I see that the authentication is Anonymous or mine is Normal.

Furthermore the FTP requires TLS protocol.

Thanks for helping me.

Comment: I believe you're supposed to be using `X509Certificate2` Certificate objects.

Comment: Show us [.NET network log](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9664650/850848) + Log of any FTP client (even GUI one) showing how you successfully authenticate from the same machine that runs your .NET code. + Full exception callstack.

Comment: Looking for .Net network log :) thx

Comment: So are you getting the *"This server requires encryption”* or not?

Comment: Why did you revert my edit? We need [mcve]. Most of the code you have posted is irrelevant to your question.

Comment: sorry i didn't see your edit :/ but why you delete unity because it's mono the problem not general C# !

Answer (score 2):

If your FTP server requires TLS/SSL encryption, you have to enable it using [`FtpWebRequest.EnableSsl`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.ftpwebrequest.enablessl):

```
request.EnableSsl = true;
```

Comment: My bad, i forgot to add this for my try :/ that's why i had the error 550 :)
i added it but no listing directory :/

Comment: If it helped this your first problem, accept the answer. And post a new question for your new problem. Do not change your question.

Comment: you help for the second answer that is totally my mistake for forget to add enableSSL :) it's not my first question :)

But for more visibility i will make a new post :)