# Loading file contents from FTP to ListBox

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio, ftp, ftp-client

I face an error when I try to load a contents of a file from FTP to `ListBox`.

[Form1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lyYWt.png) (Photo1)

[Ftp Home Including All Ftp Server File's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/60yn4.png) (Photo2)

[Error issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wkDvj.png) (Photo3), Error Happen When Press in "Ann File" (Button)

> Form1 Code (Form Class)

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Net

Public Class Form1

    Dim client As New Net.WebClient
    Dim streamreaddder As IO.StreamReader

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        ListBox1.Items.Clear()
        Dim ftp As FtpWebRequest =
            DirectCast(WebRequest.Create("ftp://Example.com/Ann.txt/"), FtpWebRequest)
        ftp.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory
        Dim ftpFiles As New ArrayList()
        ftp.Credentials = New NetworkCredential("*****", "****")
        Dim Response As FtpWebResponse = ftp.GetResponse()
        Dim responseStream As Stream = Response.GetResponseStream()
        Dim reader = New StreamReader(responseStream)

        While Not (reader.EndOfStream)
           ftpFiles.Add(reader.ReadLine())
        End While
        For Each file In ftpFiles
          ListBox1.Items.Add(file)
        Next
        reader.Close()
        responseStream.Close()
        Response.Close()
    End Sub

End Class
```

Only I want to load my FTP file (`Ann.txt`) in my listbox .

Error details:

```
System.Net.WebException
HResult=0x80131509
Message=The remote server returned an error: (550) File unavailable (e.g., file not found, no access).
Source=System
StackTrace:
at System.Net.FtpWebRequest.SyncRequestCallback(Object obj)
at System.Net.FtpWebRequest.RequestCallback(Object obj)
at System.Net.CommandStream.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
at System.IO.Stream.Close()
at System.IO.Stream.Dispose()
at System.Net.ConnectionPool.Destroy(PooledStream pooledStream)
at System.Net.ConnectionPool.PutConnection(PooledStream pooledStream, Object owningObject, Int32 creationTimeout, Boolean canReuse)
at System.Net.FtpWebRequest.FinishRequestStage(RequestStage stage)
at System.Net.FtpWebRequest.GetResponse()
at WindowsApp1.Form1.Button2_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\Ahmad\AppData\Local\Temporary Projects\WindowsApp1\Form1.vb:line 72
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.OnRun()
at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.DoApplicationModel()
at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.Run(String[] commandLine)
at WindowsApp1.My.MyApplication.Main(String[] Args) in :line 81
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To read a file contents, you have to use `DownloadFile` method, not `ListDirectory`:

```
Dim request As FtpWebRequest = WebRequest.Create("ftp://example.com/path/Ann.txt")
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile
request.Credentials = New NetworkCredential("username", "password")

Using response As FtpWebResponse = request.GetResponse(),
      stream As Stream = response.GetResponseStream(),
      reader As StreamReader = New StreamReader(stream)
    While Not reader.EndOfStream
        ListBox1.Items.Add(reader.ReadLine())
    End While
End Using
```

---

Also note:

- the use of `Using` statement;
- no need for intermediate `ArrayList()`.

---

Due to crappy implementation of the `Stream` returned by `.GetResponseStream`, the code will not work correctly if the last line is not terminated by a new line. Working this around would require much more complicate code.
See also [StreamReader ReadLine throwing disposed exception rather than returning null](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48829032/850848) (not exactly the same problem, but similar).

Comment: it important to Direct Ftp File Server into my Listbox, for new future , Like Edit it, Or Add New items inThe Ann.txt ... Etc

Comment: Also i checked Ann.Txt ,, It Exist In my ftp server , So i made 

Button 1 ( For server home Directory)

And Button 2 (For Exist File Ann.txt) 

(As i explain all that in my Code)

Comment: Button 1 (FTP Home) : Will Direct me for Ftp Server home /////

Button 2 (Ann file) : Will Direct me For Ann.Txt inside 
So will list (Ann.txt) Lines

----
For Example i presed Button 2 Will Show Me in listbox (Ann.txt) Entries in listbox1 lines

Comment: yees,, for example (Ann.txt) Contents this lines :

- worker 1
- Worker 2
- worker 3

-=-=

then will show listbox1 (the Ann.txt) lines in listbox

for this 3 lines (Worker 1,2,3)

Comment: Error View Text : https://justpaste.it/1hdej

Error View Picture : https://imgur.com/NRKFQO1

Comment: Big thx ,, its now fine .,, So last question before close that case,, i greatful for your that help,, can i make " UploadFile  " , after my listbox edited ,can i re uploaded it in same Ann.txt with Button 3 (button 2 to downloadFile) Button 3 for re upload it again from listbox) ,, so Uploadfile method, is it same like downloafile method ?!

Comment: Sorry bro., Can you give me that button 3 , Code 
, by this i will know more about that, ,,

Comment: i appreciate it, i only said Bro = Brother and it was little thing that i do for you great help/,, Any way thanks,, i also upload new question as you say,.

Comment: I know the Stackoverflow the best forever for his Dev's , Programmer's helpful,

Comment: excuse me ,, i'm new in stackoverflow, i now got what you mean about Accepting the answer, 

my sorry for that ,, Also im new on it ,, and dont have access to  Vote up, at least i have to collect 15 reputation, i try to figure About to how to accept your question ,, Thx

Comment: i got it,, Almost checked that accepted,, thanks Martin ,, i didnt was joken ,, i only didt got it clearly for your Accept that question , i didt catch how to perform that Accepted By thank,, Hope that make you fell better ,, Thx