# Upload file contents from ListBox to FTP

Tags: .net, vb.net, ftp, ftp-client, ftpwebrequest

To read a file contents to `ListBox`, I used `DownloadFile` method from my previous question
[Loading file contents from FTP to ListBox](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48836591/850848)

```
Dim request As FtpWebRequest = 
    WebRequest.Create("ftp://example.com/path/Ann.txt")
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile
request.Credentials = New NetworkCredential("username", "password")

Using response As FtpWebResponse = request.GetResponse(),
      stream As Stream = response.GetResponseStream(),
      reader As StreamReader = New StreamReader(stream)
    While Not reader.EndOfStream
        ListBox1.Items.Add(reader.ReadLine())
    End While
End Using
```

Now I want to add another button that uses `StreamWriter` and `WebRequest.GetRequestStream` to upload the contents of `ListBox` back to FTP.

Comment: Thx,, The code was in 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48836591/the-remote-server-returned-an-error-550-listbox

-=-= and someone tell me to make a new Question here again

Comment: A _"How do I do this"_ question is rarely acceptible at Stack Overflow. You need to do your own research and attempts. -- Also, **really** need to accept [**the answer Martin gave you**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48839333), seeing as you're using his code. To accept an answer press the **tick/check mark** located on the left of Martin's post so that it turns green, like in this image: http://i.stack.imgur.com/LkiIZ.png -- This is a **very** important thing to do as it shows your gratitude towards the answerer _and_ rewards him/her for helping you!

Comment: thanks,, that what i was want to make ,, i was new in stackoverflow, then he ask me for Accept the answer ,, and i didnt got it clearly ,, thanks for your important info that you gived me

Comment: Let me ask you this: _What_ is it specifically that you want to upload when clicking `Button3`?

Comment: okey about Button 3 

if i edit listbox (add lines + Edit some lines) 
when Press will Upload that lines As.txt into server again)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You basically need the code from my answer to
[How to download file from FTP and upload it again](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2450032/850848#46703249).

---

Though to easily copy contents (lines) of `ListBox`, you can slightly modify it to write line-by-line using `StreamWriter`:

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim request As FtpWebRequest =
        WebRequest.Create("ftp://example.com/path/Ann.txt")
    request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile
    request.Credentials = New NetworkCredential("username", "password")
    request.UseBinary = False

    Using stream As Stream = request.GetRequestStream(),
          writer As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter(stream)
        For index As Integer = 0 To ListBox1.Items.Count - 1
            writer.WriteLine(ListBox1.Items(index))
        Next
    End Using
End Sub
```

Comment: Before thank,, It worked Great,, Then Now Accepted Question ,, You fast and Helpful ,, And Last thing ,, Thanks