# Error 501 when connecting to Azure FTP with PowerShell but works in C#

Tags: .net, azure, powershell, ftp, webclient

I tried to use `WebClient` in PowerShell 5.1 to upload or download some file to Azure AppService hosted website. I got the FTP credential and FTP URL from my app's PublishProfile in Azure and used code below to do the task,

```
$username = "$somename"
$password = "somepassword"
$webclient = New-Object -TypeName System.Net.WebClient
$webclient.Credentials = New-Object 
System.Net.NetworkCredential($username, $password)

$localfilename = "Temp.txt"

$destUrl = "ftp://waws-someaddress.ftp.azurewebsites.windows.net/site/wwwroot/PictureReview/temp.txt"

$uri = New-Object System.Uri($destUrl)

#Write-Host $uri

$webclient.UploadFile($uri, $localfilename)
$webClient.Dispose()
```

However as I tried, whenever using `UploadFile()` or `DownloadFile()`, it always gives me

> Exception calling "UploadFile" with "2" argument(s): "The remote server returned an error: (501) Syntax error in parameters or arguments."
>   The remote server returned an error: (501) Syntax error in parameters or arguments.

I tried another public testing FTP server URL, like `ftp.dlptest.com` instead of Azure FTP URL, and it works very well. Does anyone ever meet this problem? Is this an issue of Azure App Service?

I also tried the same approach in C# code with Azure FTP URL, it also works well.

By the request of the poster, the C# code is like below:

```
WebClient client = new WebClient(); 
client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("$somename", "somepassword"); 
client.UploadFile("ftp://waws-someaddress.ftp.azurewebsites.windows.net/site/wwwroot/PictureReview/temp.txt", @"C:\users\blahblah\Desktop\temp.txt");
```

Comment: Show us your C# code that works.

Comment: Martin, I am thankful to your help, your answer is very relevant. I posted the C# code in my original post.

Comment: There's no protocol specified in your C# code. Your code will not upload the file anywhere. It will copy it to a local folder `waws-someaddress.ftp.azurewebsites.windows.net\site\wwwroot\PictureReview` (under your programs startup folder) -- Add `ftp://` to the URL --- Then your C# code will probably fail with the same error --- If it does, show us its [network log](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9664650/850848).

Comment: What does your edit mean? --- And note that your C# and PowerShell code uses a completely different URL -- Why? What does that mean?

Comment: You are right, without "ftp://" protocol, that code is not working, when I edit  that post, I must forget to put it in. Actually I just tried that code with ftp protocol in url parameter, it works fine. I just reedit that part to clarify.

Comment: You still didn't explain the the difference between URLs in PowerShell and C# code.

Comment: Martin, sorry, that is my mistake, they should be same, I edited my that url.

Comment: What about the credentials? They do not match either. Do you really have `$` sign in the username? Are you aware that you need to escape `$` sign in PowerShell string? You should really show us some *convincing* examples, that prove that your C# and PowerShell codes match.

Comment: Martin, thank you for persisting following up, when I add  ` to escape "$" in the username variable, it works, your comments solved my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your C# code shows that you have `$` sign in your username.

`$` sign has special meaning in a double-quoted PowerShell string. To use a literal `$` sign, you need to escape it with a back tick:

```
$username = "`$somename"
```

Or use single quotes:

```
$username = '$somename'
```