# How can I download a file with Hebrew characters in its name from an ftp server via .net console application?

Tags: c#, .net, utf-8, ftp, internationalization

I am using a .net console application written in C# to download certain files from an ftp server routinely, it used to work properly until there was a file with Hebrew characters, named something like that:

> 1234--אבג.jpeg

so I've tried to download the same file using both chrome and FileZilla - and encountered no problems, with neither plain nor URL encoded version of the filename.

**My problem is how to download the same file with my C# application**

I have tried:

- to escape the name as URL-encoded, worked for chrome but not my APP
- to convert the string to utf-8
- both System.Net.WebRequest and HttpClient
- finding and taking the name from response of directory listing and pasting into the request, hoping it will have the proper format.

here is my code :

```
 public static string attachmentToFile(string name, string filename)
    {
        try
        {
      
            string ftpConnection = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FtpServer"].ToString();
            string ftpUser = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FtpUser"].ToString();
            string ftpPassword = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FtpPassword"].ToString();
            string attachmentPath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["attachmentFolder"].ToString();

            Directory.CreateDirectory(attachmentPath);

            attachmentPath += '\\' + name + Path.GetExtension(filename);


            FtpWebRequest attachmentRequest = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(
                new Uri(ftpConnection + "/files_directory/" + filename)
                );


            attachmentRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(ftpUser, ftpPassword);
            attachmentRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;

            FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)attachmentRequest.GetResponse();
            var stream = response.GetResponseStream();
            FileStream saveStream = new FileStream(attachmentPath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
            //stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            stream.CopyTo(saveStream);
            saveStream.Close();
            return attachmentPath;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.LogError(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod(), ex, "failed downloading file from server: " + filename);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

the error is

> The remote server returned an error: (550) File unavailable (e.g., file not found, no access).

while in Filezilla it's successful

> Trace: CControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
> Trace:  CFtpLogonOpData::Send() in state 0
> Status: Connecting to 11.111.111.11:1111...
> Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
> Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::OnReceive()
> Response:   220---------- Welcome to Pure-FTPd [privsep] [TLS] ----------
> Response:   220-You are user number 3 of 50 allowed.
>  Response:  220-Local time is now 09:16. Server port: 1111.
> Response:   220-This is a private system - No anonymous login 
>  Response:    220 You will be disconnected after 15 minutes of inactivity.
> Trace:  CFtpLogonOpData::ParseResponse() in state 1 
> Trace:  CControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
> Trace:  CFtpLogonOpData::Send() in state 2
> Command:    AUTH TLS
> Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::OnReceive()
> Response:   234 AUTH TLS OK.
> Trace:  CFtpLogonOpData::ParseResponse() in state 2
> Status: Initializing TLS...
> Trace:  tls_layer_impl::client_handshake()
> Trace:  tls_layer_impl::continue_handshake()
> Trace:  tls_layer_impl::continue_handshake()
> Trace:  tls_layer_impl::continue_handshake()
> Trace:  tls_layer_impl::continue_handshake()
> Trace:  tls_layer_impl::continue_handshake()
> Trace:  TLS Handshake successful
> Trace:  Protocol: TLS1.2, Key exchange: ECDHE-RSA, Cipher: AES-256-GCM, MAC: AEAD
> Trace:  tls_layer_impl::verify_certificate()
> Status: Verifying certificate...
> Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::SetAsyncRequestReply
> Status: TLS connection established.
> Trace:  CControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
> Trace:  CFtpLogonOpData::Send() in state 6
> Command:    USER files@domain.co.il
> Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::OnReceive()
> Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::OnReceive()
> Response:   331 User files@domain.co.il OK. Password required
> Trace:  CFtpLogonOpData::ParseResponse() in state 6
> Trace:  CControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
> Trace:  CFtpLogonOpData::Send() in state 6
> Command:    PASS ****************
> Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::OnReceive()
> Response:   230 OK. Current restricted directory is /
> Trace:  CFtpLogonOpData::ParseResponse() in state 6
> Trace:  CControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
> Trace:  CFtpLogonOpData::Send() in state 10
> Command:    OPTS UTF8 ON
> Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::OnReceive()
> Response:   504 Unknown command
> Trace:  CFtpLogonOpData::ParseResponse() in state 10
> Trace:  CControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
> Trace:  CFtpLogonOpData::Send() in state 11
> Command:    PBSZ 0
> Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::OnReceive()
> Response:   200 PBSZ=0
> Trace:  CFtpLogonOpData::ParseResponse() in state 11
> Trace:  CControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
> Trace:  CFtpLogonOpData::Send() in state 12
> Command:    PROT P
> Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::OnReceive()
> Response:   200 Data protection level set to "private"
> Trace:  CFtpLogonOpData::ParseResponse() in state 12
> Status: Logged in
> Trace:  Measured latency of 16 ms
> Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::ResetOperation(0)
> Trace:  CControlSocket::ResetOperation(0)
> Trace:  CFtpLogonOpData::Reset(0) in state 15
> Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::FileTransfer()
> Trace:  CControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
> Trace:  CFtpFileTransferOpData::Send() in state 0
> Status: Starting download of /files_directory/1234--אבג.jpeg
> Trace:  CFtpChangeDirOpData::Send() in state 0
> Trace:  CFtpChangeDirOpData::Send() in state 2
> Command:    CWD /files_directory
> Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::OnReceive()
> Response:   250 OK. Current directory is /files_directory
> Trace:  CFtpChangeDirOpData::ParseResponse() in state 2
> Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::ResetOperation(0)
> Trace:  CControlSocket::ResetOperation(0)
> Trace:  CFtpChangeDirOpData::Reset(0) in state 2
> Trace:  CFtpFileTransferOpData::SubcommandResult(0) in state 1
> Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::SetAsyncRequestReply
> Trace:  CControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
> Trace:  CFtpFileTransferOpData::Send() in state 5
> Trace:  CFtpRawTransferOpData::Send() in state 1
> Command:    TYPE I
> Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::OnReceive()
> Response:   200 TYPE is now 8-bit binary
> Trace:  CFtpRawTransferOpData::ParseResponse() in state 1
> Trace:  CControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
> Trace:  CFtpRawTransferOpData::Send() in state 2
> Command:    PASV
> Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::OnReceive()
> Response:   227 Entering Passive Mode (11,111,111,11,111,11)
> Trace:  CFtpRawTransferOpData::ParseResponse() in state 2
> Trace:  CControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
> Trace:  CFtpRawTransferOpData::Send() in state 4
> Trace:  Binding data connection source IP to control connection source IP 10.0.0.13
> Trace:  tls_layer_impl::client_handshake()
> Trace:  Trying to resume existing TLS session.
> Command:    RETR 1234--אבג.jpeg
> Trace:  tls_layer_impl::continue_handshake()
> Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::OnReceive()
> Response:   150-Accepted data connection
> Response:   150 206.6 kbytes to download
> Trace:  CFtpRawTransferOpData::ParseResponse() in state 4
> Trace:  CControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
> Trace:  CFtpRawTransferOpData::Send() in state 5
> Trace:  tls_layer_impl::continue_handshake()
> Trace:  TLS Handshake successful
> Trace:  TLS Session resumed
> Trace:  Protocol: TLS1.2, Key exchange: ECDHE-RSA, Cipher: AES-256-GCM, MAC: AEAD
> Trace:  tls_layer_impl::verify_certificate()
> Trace:  CTransferSocket::OnConnect
> Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::OnReceive()
> Response:   226-File successfully transferred
> Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::OnReceive()
> Response:   226 0.120 seconds (measured here), 1.68 Mbytes per second
> Trace:  CFtpRawTransferOpData::ParseResponse() in state 5
> Trace:  CControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
> Trace:  CFtpRawTransferOpData::Send() in state 8
> Trace:  CTransferSocket::TransferEnd(1)
> Trace:  tls_layer_impl::shutdown()
> Trace:  tls_layer_impl::continue_shutdown()
> Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::TransferEnd()
> Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::ResetOperation(0)
> Trace:  CControlSocket::ResetOperation(0)
> Trace:  CFtpRawTransferOpData::Reset(0) in state 8
> Trace:  CFtpFileTransferOpData::SubcommandResult(0) in state 7
> Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::ResetOperation(0)
> Trace:  CControlSocket::ResetOperation(0)
> Trace:  CFtpFileTransferOpData::Reset(0) in state 7
> Status: File transfer successful, transferred 211,556 bytes in 1 second
> Status: Disconnected from server

network.log

> System.Net Information: 0 : [14564] FtpWebRequest#54024015::.ctor(ftp://files%40domain.co.il@11.111.111.11:1111/files_directory/22222222-IMG-222222-222222.jpg)
> System.Net Information: 0 : [14564] FtpWebRequest#54024015::GetResponse(Method=RETR.)
> System.Net Information: 0 : [14564] Current OS installation type is 'Client'.
> System.Net Information: 0 : [14564] RAS supported: True
> System.Net Information: 0 : [14564] FtpControlStream#13869071 - Created connection from 10.0.0.13:11111 to 11.111.111.11:1111.
> System.Net Information: 0 : [14564] Associating FtpWebRequest#54024015 with FtpControlStream#13869071
> System.Net Information: 0 : [14564] FtpControlStream#13869071 - Received response [220---------- Welcome to Pure-FTPd [privsep] [TLS] ----------
> 220-You are user number 3 of 50 allowed.
> 220-Local time is now 09:44. Server port: 1111.
> 220-This is a private system - No anonymous login
> 220 You will be disconnected after 15 minutes of inactivity.]
>
> ....
>
> 150 119.1 kbytes to download]
> System.Net Information: 0 : [14564] FtpControlStream#13869071 - Received response [226-File successfully transferred
> 226 0.052 seconds (measured here), 2.24 Mbytes per second]
>
> ....
>
> 150 4312.7 kbytes to download]
> System.Net Information: 0 : [14564] FtpControlStream#13869071 - Received response [226-File successfully transferred
> 226 1.874 seconds (measured here), 2.25 Mbytes per second]
>
> ....
>
> 150 1974.2 kbytes to download]
> System.Net Information: 0 : [14564] FtpControlStream#13869071 - Received response [226-File successfully transferred
> 226 0.884 seconds (measured here), 2.18 Mbytes per second]
> System.Net Information: 0 : [14564] FtpWebRequest#49652976::(Releasing FTP connection#13869071.)
> System.Net Information: 0 : [14564] FtpWebRequest#44223604::.ctor(ftp://files%40domain.co.il@11.111.111.11:1111/files_directory/11111111-1111111111.jpg)
> System.Net Information: 0 : [14564] FtpWebRequest#44223604::GetResponse(Method=RETR.)
> System.Net Information: 0 : [14564] Associating FtpWebRequest#44223604 with FtpControlStream#13869071
> System.Net Information: 0 : [14564] FtpControlStream#13869071 - Sending command [PASV]
> System.Net Information: 0 : [14564] FtpControlStream#13869071 - Received response [227 Entering Passive Mode (11,111,111,11,111,111)]
> System.Net Information: 0 : [14564] FtpControlStream#13869071 - Sending command [RETR files_directory/11111111-1111111111.jpg]
> System.Net Information: 0 : [14564] FtpControlStream#13869071 - Received response [150-Accepted data connection
> 150 1953.3 kbytes to download]
> System.Net Information: 0 : [14564] FtpControlStream#13869071 - Received response [226-File successfully transferred
> 226 0.929 seconds (measured here), 2.05 Mbytes per second]
> System.Net Information: 0 : [14564] FtpWebRequest#44223604::(Releasing FTP connection#13869071.)
> System.Net Information: 0 : [14564] FtpWebRequest#62468121::.ctor(ftp://files%40domain.co.il@11.111.111.11:1111/files_directory/1234--אבג.jpeg)
> System.Net Information: 0 : [14564] FtpWebRequest#62468121::GetResponse(Method=RETR.)
> System.Net Information: 0 : [14564] Associating FtpWebRequest#62468121 with FtpControlStream#13869071
> System.Net Information: 0 : [14564] FtpControlStream#13869071 - Sending command [PASV]
> System.Net Information: 0 : [14564] FtpControlStream#13869071 - Received response [227 Entering Passive Mode (11,111,111,11,111,111)]
> System.Net Information: 0 : [14564] FtpControlStream#13869071 - Sending command [RETR files_directory/1234--אבג.jpeg]
> System.Net Information: 0 : [14564] FtpControlStream#13869071 - Received response [550 Can't open files_directory/1234--אבג.jpeg: No such file or directory]
> System.Net Information: 0 : [14564] FtpWebRequest#62468121::(Releasing FTP connection#13869071.)
> System.Net Error: 0 : [14564] Exception in FtpWebRequest#62468121::GetResponse - The remote server returned an error: (550) File unavailable (e.g., file not found, no access)..
> at System.Net.FtpWebRequest.SyncRequestCallback(Object obj)
> at System.Net.FtpWebRequest.RequestCallback(Object obj)
> at System.Net.CommandStream.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
> at System.IO.Stream.Close()
> at System.IO.Stream.Dispose()
> at System.Net.ConnectionPool.Destroy(PooledStream pooledStream)
> at System.Net.ConnectionPool.PutConnection(PooledStream pooledStream, Object owningObject, Int32 creationTimeout, Boolean canReuse)
> at System.Net.FtpWebRequest.FinishRequestStage(RequestStage stage)
> at System.Net.FtpWebRequest.GetResponse()

Comment: FTP has a "usebinary" property.  Normal FTP mode is text which will filter characters.  If you do not want any filtering than use the binary mode.

Comment: And what's the problem you have? Any error? Problems with user input? File not found? be more specific

Comment: As @Gusman said, be more specific about the issue you're seeing. You probably need to `HttpUtility.UrlEncode` the filename.

Comment: Show us FileZilla verbose log file as well as [`FtpWebRequest` log file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9664650/850848).

Comment: @jdweng The question is about file names, not file contents. Binary/Text mode is irrelevant here.

Comment: @ Martin Prikryl I have edited in both logs you mentioned, still cannot find what FileZilla and chrome do right that I do wrong, except for "Command: OPTS UTF8 ON" but I don't know how to reproduce it in C# after searching

Answer (score 0, accepted):

although I didn't find the exact reason for the error, after printing FileZilla verbose log and FtpWebRequest as suggested in the comments and reading some more I have read that it's hard to change certain configurations using System.Net.WebRequest and HttpClient, so I used a 3d party library (FluentFTP) there were many configurations available but I didn't need to do anything in my case and the problem was solved by the default configurations.