The underlying connection was closed: The server committed a protocol violation C#
I am trying to upload file from my local to FTP.. but getting following error and below is my code.
FTP connection is not SFTP, but it's like TLS1.2, any idea on this.
Error
System.Net.WebException: 'The underlying connection was closed: The server committed a protocol violation

Code :
FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://test.com/products.csv");
 request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
 request.EnableSsl = true;
 ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;
 request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;

 request.KeepAlive = true;

 using (Stream fileStream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(@"C:\Users\Test\Downloads\products.csv"))
 using (Stream ftpStream = request.GetRequestStream())
 {
     fileStream.CopyTo(ftpStream);
 }


Mind the "Remarks" section in the docs on FtpWebRequest: "Important - We don't recommend that you use the FtpWebRequest class for new development. For more information and alternatives to FtpWebRequest, see WebRequest shouldn't be used on GitHub."

Post log file: https://stackoverflow.com/q/9664650/850848 + Log file from any FTP client that can successfully connect to the same server using the same login details from the same local machine, where your C# code fails.

@MartinPrikryl via Filezilla I am able to connect with this FTP detail as well as able to upload file

Please post the logs.

FTP RFC documents are old and not detailed enough to enforce consistent behaviors among implementations. So, you can find IIS FTP or .NET building FTP implementations varied from others. You might search for other .NET FTP libraries that work better.

ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true; makes your app trust any server certificate, which is a bad practise and a security risk.
request.EnableSsl = true; suggests that you want to actually use FTPS, which is fine I guess, but server has to support it as well, so that's first thing to check. Next is the TLS protocl version supported, but I suggest running a network trace, suign a tool like WireShark - https://www.wireshark.org/download.html
BTW WebRequest.Create() is obsolete.
