# Can i tweak FTP command behavior via scripts on FTP Server

Tags: c#-4.0, scripting, customization, ftp-server

I would like to know can i some way tweak the FTP command behavior say for example for STOR command.when FTP server on IIS receives STOR command from any ftp client,i would like to run  scripts having custom code(c# coding) redirecting where i want to store the file.

Regards,
Vivek

Comment: What FTP server are you using? This would be a FTP server option or extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIS 7.0 and 7.5 have an [extensibility layer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd723667%28v=vs.90%29). It does not appear to be able to change the behavior of commands (probably a good thing since they are defined by the appropriate standard) but there is a mechanism to [return a user's home directory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd692893%28v=vs.90%29), which may be what you want.

A similar (not not identical) question may be useful: [IIS FTP 7.5 Extensibility (IFtpLogProvider and logging FTP failures to the event log)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2032198/iis-ftp-7-5-extensibility-iftplogprovider-and-logging-ftp-failures-to-the-event)